# Nested Arrays work out highest sales figure for the year

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have nested arrays which contain a data string value and number value for a period of time. I want to be able to loop through these to find out which month has highest amount sales by comparing one month another e.g jan > feb, feb - march, march to april etc... and produce output which states JAN 500 or something similar, i am not able to figure how these needs to be done, i am just starting out in javscript

```js
const sales = [
  ['jan-2010', 200000],
  ['feb-2010', 400000],
  ['mar-2010', 100000]
];

for (let i = 0; i < sales.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < sales[i].length; j++)
    if (typeof sales[i][j] === "number") {
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can using `Math.max()` to find the max sale amount,then using `Array.filter()` to find the related record.

Below is a reference for you

```js
const sales = [
  ['jan-2010', 200000],
  ['feb-2010', 400000],
  ['mar-2010', 200000]
];

let maxSale = Math.max(...sales.map(e => e[1]))
let record = sales.filter(e => e[1] === maxSale )
console.log(record)
```

Comment: Maybe I have asked the question incorrectly,  the output i am after i what the difference between in sales from the previous month.  e.g the difference between jan-2010 and feb-2010 is +200000 and between feb-2010 and march-2010 its is -200000, so the output i want to see is  feb-2010 200000. hope that is clear

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
> sales.reduce((result, current) => result?.[1] > current?.[1] ? result : current);
[ 'feb-2010', 400000 ]
```

Comment: How about if there are more than one records has the same value as highest sale amount?

Comment: @flyingfox in this case it will return the last value (the more revelant in his case, where it's better to have the closest highest sale's month than the one 15 decade ago) instead of an array with all equal sale month because it will need another data's treatments afterward. He can still use `>=` operator instead of `>` if he want the first.